# how to remove widgets from widgets page?

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to remove widgets from the widgets page.  I was able to find the code to remove them, for example:

```
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
```

That removes the Meta widget.
Removing default WP widgets is easy because I can find the names of the widgets to remove.

**BUT** I'm having trouble finding the names of 3rd party widgets.  Does anyone know how to find the names of 3rd party widgets so I can target them and unregister them?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118684/get-a-list-of-all-widgets-registered-in-wordpress-admin-widgets-area#answer-118688

Comment: You find the ID of a widget inside the markup of a widget. Also you can use the plugin Adminimize, if you not familiar with coding.